# How can i get Autocomplete Address from drag event in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I created a Google Geocoder , I want to be able to pick up the auto complete address of the marker when it is dragged or clicked.

[image: This is my auto complete address map]

Here issue is while searching address there is no issue it showing exact location and giving auto complete address like Street address, city , state, zip code, country etc..

Issue is while drag the pin point one location to another location entire address is changing according to google pin location but it is not giving address sub parts like Street address, city, state, zip code, country (not updating means old search values only there)

mycode:

```
<head>
<title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #locationField, #controls {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
  }
  #autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 99%;
  }
  .label {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100px;
    color: #303030;
  }
  #address {
    border: 1px solid #000090;
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
    width: 480px;
    padding-right: 2px;
  }
  #address td {
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .field {
    width: 99%;
  }
  .slimField {
    width: 80px;
  }
  .wideField {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #locationField {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
</style>

   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA1BvEkX8v91LRu43HQe0-GNaHTVnoTSQs&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br><br>   
 <div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
</div>
 <table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
          disabled="true" name="streetnumber"></input></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
          disabled="true" name="route"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
         You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
    -->
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
          disabled="true" name="locality"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
          id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"  name="state" ></input></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
          disabled="true" name="postal_code"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
          id="country" disabled="true" name="country"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 250px;"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<script>
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };



   var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');

  function initMap() {
    var geocoder;
    var autocomplete;

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    var card = document.getElementById('locationField');
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
    // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
    // bounds option in the request.
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
      draggable: true
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);

      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }

      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
      infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      fillInAddress();

    });
  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace(input);
    console.log(place);
    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
      }
    }
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) 
{
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0]) {
      console.log(autocomplete);
  $('#autocomplete').val(results[0].formatted_address);
  google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
  $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
  $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
  infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                  }
              });       
            }
            );
         }
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I needed here according to drag the location it should change auto complete address also, Help me anyone. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, your function fillInAddress().  I changed it into so that you can directly give it the address components as a parameter.

```
function fillInAddress(new_address) {  // optional parameter
  if(typeof new_address == 'undefined') {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace(input);
  }
  else {
    place = new_address;
  }
  ...
}
```

so...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
  ...
  // do not trigger place_changed.  Instead call this:
  fillInAddress(results[0]);
  ...
})
```

full code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   element that contains the map. */

    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }

    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #locationField,
    #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
    }

    #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
    }

    .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
    }

    #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
    }

    #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .field {
        width: 99%;
    }

    .slimField {
        width: 80px;
    }

    .wideField {
        width: 200px;
    }

    #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA1BvEkX8v91LRu43HQe0-GNaHTVnoTSQs&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
</div>
<table id="address">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" name="streetnumber"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" name="route"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
     You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform    
     -->
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" name="locality"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" name="state"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" name="postal_code"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" name="country"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 250px;"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
    <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
    <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
    <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<script>
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };



    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');

    function initMap() {
        var geocoder;
        var autocomplete;

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: -33.8688,
                lng: 151.2195
            },
            zoom: 13
        });
        var card = document.getElementById('locationField');
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
        // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
        // bounds option in the request.
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
            draggable: true
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place);

            if (!place.geometry) {
                // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
                // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
                window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            }
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
            }

            infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
            infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
            infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            fillInAddress();

        });

        function fillInAddress(new_address) { // optional parameter
            if (typeof new_address == 'undefined') {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace(input);
            } else {
                place = new_address;
            }
            //console.log(place);
            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': marker.getPosition()
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        console.log(autocomplete);
                        $('#autocomplete').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                        $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                        $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        // google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
                        fillInAddress(results[0]);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Emmanuel Delay right now my google api some issue is there i am not getting map i let you know whether it is working or not

Comment: I think i exceeded number of requests

Comment: As far as you know, the code is okay, right?  Just the request limit that causes problems?

Comment: Finally everything working fine @ Emmanuel Delay Thank you so much every thing fine now, i have one doubt i tried to populate database address (full address value) to input type that time map is not showing while choosing suggestion then showing the map is there any way to without selecting suggestion show the map ( this one only for rendering address from database scenario)